# Is it possible to publishLocal in development mode with scala-sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, chisel

I'm writing a library package that I wan't to use in an other (local) project.
Does I have to relaunch command :

```scala
$ sbt publishLocal
```

Each time I make a modification or is it possible to automatize it ?

I'm using [this Chisel-template](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-template/blob/release/build.sbt) project for build.sbt.

Comment: `~publishLocal` ?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `~publishLocal`: `~<any task>` trigger any task on source change.

Comment: That interesting but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a mechanism like "python setup.py develop" that install the package but use a direct link to sources in local. With your solution I have to keep sbt running in a console.

Comment: There is no need to run SBT interactive shell to execute SBT task: `sbt <task>`

Comment: yes I now, but I have to run sbt <task> and keep it running.

Comment: What you can easily run as background process (`bg` or `&`) ...